# How to send the emails related to the user account in HTML?

Tags: 8, theming, users, emails

I want to send the emails related to the user account in HTML version:

- forgotten password
- new account
- account canceled
- ...

If I make a copied paste of my HTML code, it does not work.

```
/admin/config/people/accounts
```

How to send the emails related to the user account in HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

The [mimemail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module is what usually would be the right solution for this, but is seems to contain an error, so that it does'nt add HTML to the user account mails.

Check issue here, [mimemail issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail/issues/3005820).

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, I will update when I am on my computer

Comment: I have already installed "Mailsystem" and "Swiftmailer", mail the emails sent for the user account's event remains in plain text.

Comment: @553aa08930 I am having the same issues. With SwiftMailer, the registration e-mails do not get themed. While using MimeMail they do get themed but the body of the e-mail is all collapsed and plain text.

Comment: @NoSssweat Ok, so you have the same problem as me. I searched and I did not find anything to send these emails in HTML

Comment: @553aa08930 I created an [issue for MimeMail here](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail/issues/3005820)

Comment: @553aa08930 I have added a patch, give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Mimemail helps you send the emails with html. Are you sure you have updates those system emails with html/css?

With mimemail, it is not guaranteed that user will see email in html. User clients may be configure to receive plain text emails only.

[Edit]
Have a look at this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem

Comment: Yes. I can send emails in HTML format. But it does not work with user account events.

Comment: what haapens when you add HTML tags on user account related emails?